# Find a list of numbers, using a text file, in Notepad++

Tags: full-text-search, notepad++

I am wanting to do a search in Notepad++ (or any other text editor), that will allow me to give a list of numbers; say:

```
text1.txt:
00124573
00758392
00856375
04800372
73049002
etc.
```

And then put it through the text editor, and then write out all the non-matches to a text file?

So my original.txt would look like this:

```
141,04800372,0,"S","AK","C","TEXT"
151,856375,0,"S","AK","C","TEXT"
152,73049002,0,"S","AK","C","TEXT"
153,124573,0,"S","AK","C","TEXT"
131,758392,0,"S","AK","C","TEXT"
```

Maybe that a batch file may be a better way of doing this?

So in theory, the original.txt would take text1.txt and search for the first number in the original.txt and write out only if it can't find the number.

Comment: Notepad++ by itself is not the right tool, and powerful enough, to do what you want here.  Do you have any other tools at your disposal?

Comment: I don't. Well I tried using Excel, but the file size is too big to open in Excel.

Comment: I think you will need something like Java, C#, Perl, or maybe some bash magic.

Comment: Have an upvote so that maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I am going to read the text1.txt into C# code, then will use that to search each line in the original.txt file. I guess this is the only way.